# ClassCastException on itself after redeploy of same application`

Tags: jpa, netbeans, glassfish, classcastexception

I am developing a JSF application with Netbeans and Glassfish. When I change something and Netbeans redeploys to Glassfish, then a ClassCastException is been thrown on the entity class itself.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.twibu.entity.Tipper cannot be cast to com.twibu.entity.Tipper
    at com.twibu.service.TipperService.findByUseridPwd(TipperService.java:22)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

---

For reference, here's the full stack trace:

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TipperService, method: public com.twibu.entity.Tipper com.twibu.service.TipperService.findByUseridPwd(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5113)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4901)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.findByUseridPwd(Unknown Source)
    at com.twibu.service.__EJB31_Generated__TipperService__Intf____Bean__.findByUseridPwd(Unknown Source)
    at com.twibu.bean.AuthBean.login(AuthBean.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.twibu.entity.Tipper cannot be cast to com.twibu.entity.Tipper
    at com.twibu.service.TipperService.findByUseridPwd(TipperService.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 44 more
```

Here's the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tipper")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findById", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t WHERE t.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findByName", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t WHERE t.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findByUserid", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t WHERE t.userid = :userid"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findByPwd", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t WHERE t.pwd = :pwd"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Tipper.findByEmail", query = "SELECT t FROM Tipper t WHERE t.email = :email")})

@NamedNativeQueries({
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Tipper.findByUseridPwd", query = "" +
        "SELECT a.id AS id, " +
        "       a.idgruppe AS idgruppe, " +
        "       a.name AS name, " +
        "       a.userid AS userid, " +
        "       a.pwd AS pwd, " +
        "       a.email AS email " +
        "FROM tipper AS a " +
        "WHERE     a.userid = ? " +
        "      AND a.pwd = MD5(?)",
            resultClass=Tipper.class)})

public class Tipper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20130311L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    @Column(name = "pwd")
    private String pwd;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tipper")
    private Collection<Zulassung> zulassungCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idgruppe", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Gruppe idgruppe;

    public Tipper() {
    }

    public Tipper(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Tipper(Integer id, String name, String userid, String pwd, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Zulassung> getZulassungCollection() {
        return zulassungCollection;
    }

    public void setZulassungCollection(Collection<Zulassung> zulassungCollection) {
        this.zulassungCollection = zulassungCollection;
    }

    public Gruppe getIdgruppe() {
        return idgruppe;
    }

    public void setIdgruppe(Gruppe idgruppe) {
        this.idgruppe = idgruppe;
    }

    public boolean isUser() {
        return idgruppe.getName().equals("user")  ||  idgruppe.getName().equals("admin");
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return idgruppe.getName().equals("admin");
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Tipper)) {
            return false;
        }
        Tipper other = (Tipper) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.twibu.entity.Tipper[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

And here's the service class:

```
@Singleton
public class TipperService extends AbstractService {

    public Tipper findByUseridPwd(String userid, String pwd) {
        Query nq = getTwibuManager().createNamedQuery("Tipper.findByUseridPwd");
        nq.setParameter(1, userid);
        nq.setParameter(2, pwd);
        return (Tipper)nq.getSingleResult();
    }

}
```

Comment: It would have been better to post the relevant code i.e. `TipperService` (that is not in your post) instead of almost your JSF/PrimeFaces code and the managed bean that is not directly related to the problem (which misleads to find the problem).

Comment: You're definitley right. I apologize. I forgot this code. I'll post it when I'm home again. But unfortunately it might be tomorrow evening my time. In the meanwhile I shortly describe the called method. It takes the Namedquery and makes select. Because the user is already logged in the result is definitely exactly one row. And an instance of the Class Tipper is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the old application is not getting undeployed.

If you are not using a container managed persistence unit, then you need to close your EntityManagerFactory when undeploying.

Comment: @james I have the same problem, how can I ensure that my EntityManagerFactory are being closed before redeployment?