# java - java.lang.ClassCastException on calling getSingleResult() method?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jpa, jdbc

I have the following java class to connect and query MySQL database using JPA:

```
public class UserEntityManager {

private EntityManagerFactory emf;
private EntityManager em;
private EntityTransaction tx;

public UserEntityManager() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("OmegaThingsPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    tx = em.getTransaction();
}

public User getUser(String username, String password) {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u "
            + "WHERE u.userUsername = :userUsername "
            + "AND u.userPassword = :userPassword");
    query.setParameter("userUsername", username);
    query.setParameter("userPassword", password);
    User user;
    try {
        user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return user;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception ****************** ");
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return null;
    } 
}
}
```

I'm always getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.omegathings.persistant.User cannot be cast to com.omegathings.persistant.User
```

I tried getResultList().get(0), but it didn't work also, what I'm missing here?

**UPDATE:**
Restarting the glassfish server (Version 4.1) will solve the problem temporary, but then on modifying the code and redeploying the application, I'm getting the exception again.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that on redeploying the application I'm getting 2 different class loaders as the following:

```
WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/)  
WebappClassLoader (delegate=true)
```

**UPDATE:**
Printing out the parent of the 2 above classloaders results in the following:

```
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@5b11b82d  
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@5b11b82d
```

As you can see, at first deployment, the Ids are identical.
Now on the second deployment I got:

```
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@57c83b1d  
org.glassfish.internal.api.DelegatingClassLoader@5b11b82d
```

Where 2 parents have a different Ids, I'm not sure if this will help in solving my problem.

Comment: Just an observation. Read operations don't need a transaction.

Comment: That error message seems to suggest that the class `User` has been loaded with two different `ClassLoader`s. Try `System.out.println(User.class.getClassLoader());` and `System.out.println(query.getSingleResult().getClass().getClassLoader());`. If you get different results it explains why the cast fails.

Comment: pbabcdefp, you're right, at first deployment I got the 2 classloaders as: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/).....then after deploying again I got......:
WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) and WebappClassLoader (delegate=true). What is the cause? and how to solve it?

Comment: I confess I don't know how to solve it. All I did was google "ClassCastException same class". There are other questions on SO on this so I'd have a look at those.

Comment: Why create a query inside the transaction and then execute it outside the transaction? Seems a very strange thing to do

Comment: Neil Stockton, sorry, forgot to remove transaction lines from previous code test, now code is updated.

Comment: pass in (to the query) the result class as the entity class ... that way it knows which class to instantiate using? maybe worth a try

Comment: Is the JPA jar (`hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-x.y.Final.jar` or whatever you are using) deployed as part of the webapp or is it "shared" on the server container?

Comment: @Clemens Klein-Robbenhaar, I'm not using any specific JPA jar, I think I'm using the JPA embedded in the glassfish server (V4.1).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774661/classcastexception-on-itself-after-redeploy-of-same-application

Comment: @Clemens Klein-Robbenhaar, by seeing my posted code, I'm always closing factory. all I need to do is to define a new object of [UserEntityManager] then calling [getUser] method, and [getUser] method should take care of closing the factory, Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out the problem after many, many tests....
The problem is in the following websocket code:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/endpoint/{authentication}")
public class WSManager {  
UserEntityManager userEntityManager = new UserEntityManager();  
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("authentication") String authString) {  
User user = new User();
user = (User) userEntityManager.getUser(parameter[0]);}
```

The problem is instantiating **UserEntityManager** class outside any of the following websocket class methods (onOpen, onMessage, onError, onClose).

Just moving the instantiation inside onOpen method will solve the problem.

I can't elaborate on the reason of such behavior, so, may some experts do.